# Training NLTK Brill tagger but using a txt file as an input

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

Hye everyone. I'm now doing my final year project named "Part-Of-Speech Tagger for Malay Language using Brill Tagger".

I want to ask about how to train a tagged sentences that i have save in txt file? The input should be in txt files then is being train using brill tagger. after that, i will used a txt file to be the test data. but, i stuck on the train part.can you help me?

here are some of my codes.

```
import nltk  
f = open('gayahidupsihat_tagged.txt')  
malay_tagged = f.read()   

def train_brill_tagger(train_data):
    # Modules for creating the templates.
    from nltk.tag import UnigramTagger
    from nltk.tag.brill import SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate, ProximateTokensTemplate
    from nltk.tag.brill import ProximateTagsRule, ProximateWordsRule
    # The brill tagger module in NLTK.
    from nltk.tag.brill import FastBrillTaggerTrainer
    unigram_tagger = UnigramTagger(train_data)
    templates = [SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule, (1,1)),
                 SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule, (2,2)),
                 SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule, (1,2)),
                 SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule, (1,3)),
                 SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateWordsRule, (1,1)),
                 SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateWordsRule, (2,2)),
                 SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateWordsRule, (1,2)),
                 SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateWordsRule, (1,3)),
                 ProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule, (-1, -1), (1,1)),
                 ProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateWordsRule, (-1, -1), (1,1))]

    trainer = FastBrillTaggerTrainer(initial_tagger=unigram_tagger,
                                   templates=templates, trace=3,
                                   deterministic=True)
    brill_tagger = trainer.train(train_data, max_rules=10)
    print
    return brill_tagger    

malay_train = (malay_tagged[:10]) 
malay_test = (malay_tagged[10:15]) 
malay20 = malay_tagged[20]

mt = train_brill_tagger(malay_train)    
print mt.tag(malay20)
```

actually, i want to train a tagged paragraph, after that, i will test it using other paragraph. After that, i will use a tagged sentences to evaluate the brill tagger as the result.

example :

i train this (`gayahidupsihat_train.txt`) -- all one line of input really:

```
Gaya\NN hidup\NN sihat\VB boleh\MD lah\UH ditakrifkan\VBZ sebagai\DT
satu\CD amalan\VBZ kehidupan\NN yang\DT membawa\VBZ impak\NN positif\NN
kepada\TO diri\NN seseorang\NN ,\, keluarganya\NN dan\CC masyarakat\NN.
Antara\IN contoh\NN kehidupan\NN yang\DT sihat\VB ialah\DT individu\NN
tersebut\EX hidup\VB dengan\DT penuh\RB ceria\RB tanpa\NN mengalami\VBZ
sebarang\NN masalah\NN yang\DT boleh\MD menjejaskan\VBZ kehidupannya\NN
untuk\TO satu\CD tempoh\NN tertentu\EX pula\DT .\. Sudah\EX pasti\RB
dalam\DT kehidupan\NN era\NN moden\NN yang\DT begitu\DT banyak\RB
tekanan\VB ini\DT gaya\NN hidup\NN sihat\VB menjadi\VBZ satu\NUM
matlamat\NN yang\DT perlu\MD dicapai\VBZ segera\VB. Oleh\PDT itu\DT ,\,
terdapat\EX pelbagai\NN tindakan\VBZ yang\DT boleh\MD dilakukan\VBZ
untuk\TO mencapai\VBZ matlamat\NN ini\DT .\.
```

then i want to test with this (`gayahidupsihat_test.txt`):

```
Tindakan\VBP awal\VB ialah\DT seseorang\NN itu\DT perlu\MD
mengamalkan\VBD satu\CD bentuk\NN pemakanan\NN yang\DT seimbang\NN
dalam\IN kehidupannya\VBZ .\.Dalam\IN keadaan\NN kehidupan\NN sebenar\JJ
,\, orang\NN ramai\JJ lebih\JJR suka\VB mengambil\VBZ makanan\NN yang\DT
bersifat\VBZ mudah\JJ seperti\DT mengamalkan\VBZ pengambilan\VBD makanan\NN
ringan\JJ ataupun\CC makanan\NN segera\NN .\. TidaK\DT kurang\JJR juga\DT
masyarakat\NN kita\PRP hari\NN ini\DT yang\DT lupa\VB kesan\NN pengambilan\VBZ
makanan\NN berlemak\JJR ataupun\CC makanan\NN yang\DT mempunyai\VBZ
kandungan\NN garam\NN ,\. gula\NN atau\DT sodium\FW glutamit\FW yang\DT
tinggi\JJ .\. Hal\IN ini\DT boleh\MD mendatangkan\VBZ pelbagai\NN penyakit\NN
kronik\JJ seperti\DT sakit\JJ jantung\NN ,\, darah\NN tinggi\JJ
ataupun\CC kencing\NN manis\JJ yang\DT juga\DT menjadi\MD punca\NN kematian\NN
tertinggi\JJS di\IN negara\NN kita\PRP .\.
```

After that, I will use some `tagged_words` to try the tagger and evaluate it.

The English version shows output like this:

```
Training Brill tagger on 500 sentences...
Finding initial useful rules...
Found 10210 useful rules.

           B      |
   S   F   r   O  |        Score = Fixed - Broken
   c   i   o   t  |  R     Fixed = num tags changed incorrect -> correct
   o   x   k   h  |  u     Broken = num tags changed correct -> incorrect
   r   e   e   e  |  l     Other = num tags changed incorrect -> incorrect
   e   d   n   r  |  e
------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
  46  46   0   0  | TO -> IN if the tag of the following word is 'AT'
  18  20   2   0  | TO -> IN if the tag of words i+1...i+3 is 'CD'
  14  14   0   0  | IN -> IN-TL if the tag of the preceding word is
                  |   'NN-TL', and the tag of the following word is
                  |   'NN-TL'
  11  11   0   1  | TO -> IN if the tag of the following word is 'NNS'
  10  10   0   0  | TO -> IN if the tag of the following word is 'JJ'
   8   8   0   0  | , -> ,-HL if the tag of the preceding word is 'NP-
                  |   HL'
   7   7   0   1  | NN -> VB if the tag of the preceding word is 'MD'
   7  13   6   0  | NN -> VB if the tag of the preceding word is 'TO'
   7   7   0   0  | NP-TL -> NP if the tag of words i+1...i+2 is 'NNS'
   7   7   0   0  | VBN -> VBD if the tag of the preceding word is
                  |   'NP'`
```

Comment: oh the coding didn't appear formatted.

Comment: yes. thank you sundar nataraj. I'm new here. :)

Comment: What does the input look like? Ten sentences (if that's what we are looking at) is a very small training corpus.

Comment: ohh i just try to make a very simple system first. Because i had try many times, but it still cannot run.

Comment: this is some of the words in gayahidupsihat_tagged.txt..                                         Gaya\NN hidup\NN sihat\VB boleh\MD lah\UH ditakrifkan\VBZ sebagai\DT satu\CD amalan\VBZ kehidupan\NN yang\DT membawa\VBZ impak\NN positif\NN

Comment: Please update your question with a sample. So one token/tag pair per line?

Comment: i had discover the correct way. thanks all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your input files (both train and test) into the format that the NLTK toolchain recognizes: A file is a list (or sequence) of sentences, a sentence is a list of tagged words, and a tagged word is a tuple of two strings, `(word, tag)`. In your code, `malay_tagged` is a simple string (i.e., a sequence of characters).

It's not hard to do it yourself, but the NLTK's `nltk.corpus.reader.TaggedCorpusReader` can parse your file for you. Just make sure to tell it that the word-tag separator in your file is a backslash (`"\\"`).